# Pandas dataframe slice by sort result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 2.5, 3.4,2.6,2.6,3.4,3.4,2.6,1.1,1.1,3.3], list('AAABBBBABCBDDD'), [1.1, 1.7, 2.5, 2.6, 3.3, 3.8,4.0,4.2,4.3,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.7,4.8], ['x/y/z','x/y','x/y/z/n','x/u','x','x/u/v','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/b','-','x/y','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/w'],['1','3','3','2','4','2','5','3','6','3','5','1','1','1']]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
```

df:

```
   col1 col2 col3     col4 col5
0   1.1    A  1.1    x/y/z    1
1   1.1    A  1.7      x/y    3
2   1.1    A  2.5  x/y/z/n    3
3   2.6    B  2.6      x/u    2
4   2.5    B  3.3        x    4
5   3.4    B  3.8    x/u/v    2
6   2.6    B    4    x/y/z    5
7   2.6    A  4.2        x    3
8   3.4    B  4.3  x/u/v/b    6
9   3.4    C  4.5        -    3
10  2.6    B  4.6      x/y    5
11  1.1    D  4.7    x/y/z    1
12  1.1    D  4.7        x    1
13  3.3    D  4.8  x/u/v/w    1
```

I want to get the following output

```
t = df.groupby('col5').col1.size()
t.sort()
t[-3:]
```

Out Put:

```
col5
5       2
1       4
3       4
```

Then I want to get the 'col1' values corresponding to 'col5' values. I can get one by one like following.

```
df[df['col5'] == '5']['col1'].unique()
```

But I want to get all all three(or n numbers) at once. Is it possible? How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin` to filter in the values you want:

```
In [34]: df[df.col5.isin(t[-3:].index)]['col1'].unique()
Out[34]: array([1.1, 2.6, 3.4, 3.3], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks, This is some thing additinal, For the same dataframe. Lets say I have a list based on "col1": li = ['1.1', '2.5']. I want to get "col3" value for the corresponding "col1"values.....df[df['col1'].isin(li)]['col3'].unique()...this is not working?

Comment: Use float instead of string `li = [1.1, 2.5]`

Comment: List is generated by li.append() function, So how to use float?

Comment: Not sure what you want, can you explain more clearly by update you post?

Comment: Thank you very much waitingkuo!. I'll try to post the question in a new post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want (which 3 numbers do you need?), but you may want to look into the groups parameter of the groupby object:

```
In [398]: df.groupby('col5').groups
```

This returns the group keys and the indexes of the groups

```
Out[398]: 
{'1': [0L, 11L, 12L, 13L],
 '2': [3L, 5L],
 '3': [1L, 2L, 7L, 9L],
 '4': [4L],
 '5': [6L, 10L],
 '6': [8L]}
```

from that result you can build any output you want:

```
In [399]: {col5:df.lookup(ix_list,["col1"]*len(ix_list)) for col5, ix_list in df.groupby('col5').groups.iteritems()}
Out[399]: 
{'1': array([ 1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  3.3]),
 '2': array([ 2.6,  3.4]),
 '3': array([ 1.1,  1.1,  2.6,  3.4]),
 '4': array([ 2.5]),
 '5': array([ 2.6,  2.6]),
 '6': array([ 3.4])}
```

Comment: I learnt some valuable things from your answer..:)Any way waitingkuo has provided the answer I expected!

Comment: Thanks, glad you got a satisfactory answer :-)